# Failed to Fetch error when trying to build docker image (while RUN apt-get update)

Tags: python, linux, docker, ubuntu, debian

I'm trying to create a flask-docker project, but i  also need some tools from linux.
So i have a debian:latest base image for my dockerfile, in which i want to install
python3 and dieharder(the package i need for my project).
But every time i try to build the image with following command:
`docker build --no-cache --pull -t backend .` 
I get 3 packages that fail to fetch:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/gcc_10.2.1-1_amd64.deb  Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 151.101.14.132 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/g%2b%2b_10.2.1-1_amd64.deb  Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 151.101.14.132 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update --fix-missing -y && apt-get install -y python3-pip && apt-get install -y dieharder' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I'm already running everything in one RUN command and also using --no-cache, but i still
get these errors. Also i could'nt find anyone else with these specific errors.
So i'm asking for Your help, because i don't know what else i can do.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing -y && apt-get install -y python3-pip && apt-get install -y dieharder

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ] 

CMD ["main.py"]
```

Could it be a problem that im doing all this on a VM? Is there any further information
you need to help me? Please let me know, this is my first question ever, so sry if it's not that good :)
P.S. i don't really need to use debian as a base image but i would prefer to. I also tried Ubuntu and got the same error, so i don't think that thats the problem.

Comment: Hi civlon! Cheers on your first question!

I built your Dockerfile and I faced no issues. This seems to be related to your VM, most likely to the networking configuration. I'm no networking expert, but I'll try to help :).

A couple of things:
  1. Where exactly are you running this? VirtualBox, WSL, something else?
  2. Can you try and ping that IP address you see in the error message? Just to verify the network connectivity: `ping 151.101.14.132`

Comment: Hi @PabloPaglilla thanks  for your help :) 
Im using VirtualBox and have win10 hast my host system (the VM is debian).
When i ping the address there seems to be no problem.
And as i said in my update answer when i add the command to install gcc and g++ seperatly, my dockerfile builds, which is a bit weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
It seems like i solved this problem, although I'm not really sure why it works now.
I had to change my run command and install gcc and g++ independently from
apt-get update. I don't know if this is an elegant solution, but it works for now.
If anyone has a smoother solution pls let me know :) 
Anyway here is my final Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install gcc-10 -y && apt-get install g++-10 -y && apt-get install -y python3-pip && apt-get install -y dieharder

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ] 

CMD ["main.py"]
```